# program stuck because of missing thrown events

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

This is the case:

A business has several sites, each site holds several cameras that take alt of pictures daily (about a thousand pictures each). These pictures are then stored in a folder (one folder for a day) on one computer.

The business own an image analyzing program that gets an "in.xml" file as input and returns an "out.xml" file, for analyzing of one picture. This program  must used and cannot be changed.
I wrote a UI for that program that runs on that folder and processes each camera from each site, sending pic after pic to that program which runs as a separate process.
Because this processing is async I have used events at the start and end of every pic's handling, and the same for sites and cameras on sites.

The program run on that business greatly, but sometimes it gets stuck after handling a pic, like it has missed the end_pic_analizing event, and is still waiting for it to be thrown.
I tried putting a timer for every picture, that moves to the next pic in such cases, but it still got stuck again, acting like is was missing the timer event as well.

This bug happens too many times, even when running almost as single process at that computer, and has got stuck even at the start of the process (happened at the third picture once). this bug doesn't depend on specific pictures either, because it can be stuck at different pics or not be stuck at all, while running repeatedly on the same folder.

Code samples:
on the Image class:

```
    static public void image_timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //stop timer and calculate the how much time left for next check for file. 
        _timer.Stop();
        _timerCount += (int)_timer.Interval;
        int timerSpan = (int)(Daily.duration * 1000) - _timerCount; 
                //daily.duration is the max duration for seekin the "out.xml" file before quiting.
        if (timerSpan < _timer.Interval) _timer.Interval = timerSpan + 1;

        //check for file and analize it.
        String fileName = Daily.OutPath + @"\out.xml";
        ResultHandler.ResultOut output = ResultHandler.GetResult(ref _currentImage);

        //if no file found and there is time left wait and check again
        if (output == ResultHandler.ResultOut.FileNotFound && timerSpan > 0)
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }
        else //file found or time left
        {
             if (MyImage.ImageCheckCompleted != null)
                MyImage.ImageCheckCompleted(_currentImage); //throw event
                // the program is probably got stuck here.
        }
```

On camera class:

```
    static public void Camera_ImageCheckCompleted(MyImage image)
    {
        //if this is not the last image.  (parent as Camera )
        if (image.Id + 1 < image.parent.imageList.Count)
        {
            image.parent.imageList[image.Id + 1].RunCheck(); //check next image
        }
        else
        {
            if (Camera.CameraCheckCompleted != null)
                Camera.CameraCheckCompleted(image.parent); // throw event
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code to show how you are firing and handling these events?

Comment: Code of the firing and handling added.

Comment: I realize english probably isn't your native language, but it helps to use the right terms.  You don't "throw" an event, you fire or raise it.  You "throw" an exception.  I say this because it can be confusing to use terms that are used for something else.

Comment: Mystere Man: You're right about English not being my native languege. Thanks to people like you a man can gain much more from this site, not only programming solutions.

Comment: @Seffix: I just read through your question again. The third-party program that you're using--if you invoked it from the command line, would you see a prompt for the next command immediately, or would it block until the image was processed? In other words, are you wrapping the call to it in an asynchronous thread, or is it running asynchronously all by itself?

Comment: The third party program is not a console app but a backgroung app. Moreover, it can't work in parralel mode. that why I had to do it in serial.   Actually, I can use a timer and use the AutoResetEvent.waitone() to wait until having result, but I don't know what is better, a thread that is opened and closed thousands of times, a lock like you suggest or the sleep() method. what do you think?

Comment: Hmm, that does complicate things. I suppose having a single thread that sleeps for a short time is probably about the best you can do in that case.

Comment: OK thanks. I think I'll leave it that way. I'll check it at run time and come back if anything new apear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have any error handling or logging code, so if an exception is thrown your program will halt and you might not have a record of what happened. This is especially true since your program is processing the images asynchronously, so the main thread may have already exited by the time an error occurs in one of your processing threads.

So first and foremost, I would suggest throwing a `try/catch` block around all the code that gets run in the separate thread. If an exception gets thrown there, you will want to catch that and either fire `ImageCheckCompleted` with some special event arguments to indicate there was an error or fire some other event that you create specifically for when errors occur. That way your program can continue to process even if an exception is thrown inside your code.

```
try
{
    //... Do your processing

    // This will happen if everything worked correctly.
    InvokeImageCheckCompleted(new ImageCheckCompletedEventArgs();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // This will happen if an exception got thrown.
    InvokeImageCheckCompleted(new ImageCheckCompletedEventArgs(e);
}
```

For the sake of simplicity, I'd suggest using a `for` loop to process each image. You can use a `ManualResetEvent` to block execution until the `ImageCheckCompleted` event fires for each check. This should make it easier to log the execution of each loop, catch errors that may be preventing the `ImageCheckCompleted` event from firing, and even possibly move on to process the next image if one of them appears to be taking too long.

Finally, if you can make your image processing thread-safe, you might consider using `Parallel.ForEach` to make it so that multiple images can be processed at the same time. This will probably significantly improve the overall speed of processing the batch.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was my first thought but I didn't know how to implement it. But in my case the second thread will be opened and be closed about thousands times, is this situation more stable than using events?

Comment: Well, I used your idea but decided to use `Thread.sleep(500);` instead. I will check this and hope it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @Seffix: I thought more about this overnight and improved my answer. How are you using `Thread.sleep(500)`? That sounds like a hack that will either make your code go a lot slower, or will be likely to cause errors, or both. A `ManualResetEvent` really is not difficult to use. Don't be afraid of it just because you've never done it before.

Comment: well, one of the requirements was to check every 500ms if the "out.xml" file apear, so I used a while loop, which works while file haven't found and the 10sec haven't yet. in the loop I used the sleep() method and afterwards check for the file. I did this to avoid the async events of a timer. Now, according to parralel processing of the images see my comment above.